# Dynamic map of objects in Typescript and angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a map structure to fill it dynamically with information from different sources:

```
export class VideoDataMap {
    [videoId: string]: {
        url: string,
        name: string
    };
}
```

The problem is that when i assign data to the object attributes, it says the object is undefined. If I assign a string and not the object, it works.
Anyone knows what i am missing here?

```
  public videoDataMap = new VideoDataMap();
```

This does not throw an error (but we are not using the object attributes)

```
  this.videoDataMap[videoId] = url;
```

This throws an error

```
   this.videoDataMap[videoId].url = url;  

   error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'url' of undefined
```

Thank you very much
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion comes because you've defined a Typescript class with structure, but not real fields. That is, the after constructed, you'll get a Javascript empty object, which makes complete sense as initially it's a map with no keys set.

It's easy to see looking into the transpiled code (for example using http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Typescript:

```
export class VideoDataMap {
    [videoId: string]: {
        url: string,
        name: string
    };
}
```

Generated Javascript:

```
var VideoDataMap = (function () {
    function VideoDataMap() {
    }
    return VideoDataMap;
}());
exports.VideoDataMap = VideoDataMap;
```

Which means, when you do:

`let videoDataMap = new VideoDataMap();`

You'll get something similar to:

`var videoDataMap = {}`

And hence when you do `videoDataMap["myVideoId1"].anyProp`, you'll get the `TypeError` because `videoDataMap["myVideoId1"]` hasn't been initialized.

An alternative would be defining it like:

```
class VideoDataItem{
    public url: string;
    public name: string;
    constructor(u: string, n: string){
        this.url = u;
        this.name = n;
    }
}

class VideoDataMap {
    [videoId: string]: VideoDataItem;
}
```

And using it like in the following running example: https://glot.io/snippets/ervh3vtbg9

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works very well, very nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

How 'bout this

```
if (this.videoDataMap[videoId]) // check if there's an object
    this.videoDataMap[videoId]["url"] = url; // only assign this field
else // is unassigned
    this.videoDataMap[videoId] = {url : url}; // initialize new object
```

Comment: thanks, the problem is that then i loose the other attributes of the object (name). i want to asign them separately.

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked but i needed to include all the atttributes in the initizalization:    this.videoDataMap[videoId] = {url : url, name:""}

Comment: you can add new fields with the bracket notation like this ```obj['field'] = 'value'```, so you dont need to add empty values when creating it the first time